# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException error when I have post method on route

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am doing an ajax request with jquery and I want to send one data to the server (the id of the clicked button) so I can make the correct query and return the correct reponse. The idea is that after I click a button I should make the ajax call to request a datatable.
My jquery function looks like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){

                var dep_id =  $(this).attr('id');

                var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {

                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                            "url" : '{!! route('workerDepData') !!}'  , 
                            "type" : "POST" ,
                            "data" : { id: dep_id } 
                        },
                 columns: [
                        { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                        { data: 'worker_name' , name:'name' },
                        { data: 'role', name: 'role' },                     
                        { data: 'dep_name' , name:'dep_id'} ,
                        { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' } ,
                        {
                                "className":      "details",
                                "orderable":      false,
                                "data":           null,
                                "defaultContent": '<button class="btn btn-success" id="show">Show</button>'           }
                    ] 
            } );
```

My route is like below:

```
Route::post('/dep/fetch/workers' , 'DepsController@fetch_workers')->name('workerDepData');
```

My fetch_workers function inside the controller has this code:

```
 public function fetch_workers()
    {

        $workers =  DB::table('workers')
                    ->where('workers.dep_id' , '=' ,request('id'))
                    ->join('departaments' , 'workers.dep_id' , '=' , 'departaments.id')
                    ->select('workers.id' , 'workers.name as worker_name' , 'workers.role' , 'departaments.name as dep_name' , 'workers.created_at')
                    ->get();
        $ajaxResponse = Datatables::of($workers)->make(true);
        return $ajaxResponse;
    }
```

After I click the button I get an error and when I check the response from the server due to the ajax request , I see a json file which have an exception at

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException.

I check  for this kind of exception and I saw it was due to a route using get instead of post. My route as you can see is using post so I don't understand why is this exception.

Comment: can you post whole stacktrace ? you can find it under network tab in chrome developer tools. its most likely a CSRF token issue I would say

Comment: @AnarBayramov you were right , thank you :)

Comment: I am writing an answer then :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As I have mentioned in comments. Its **CSRF** token issue.

In order to fix it

1) You can exclude your URI for CSRF

2) You can put csrf_token() to your ajax request.

Detailed explaination can be found here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Answer (score 5):

You must include CSRF token in both blade form and post method.

```
var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
```

and pass together with other data.

```
data: { _token:_token , etc:etc },
```

have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel: For those who are facing with csrf issue with ajax in laravel

[image]

```js
<?php

if(condition){
  
   $updated_field = 'User' ;
   
  $id = $t->updated_value;

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo '$(document).ready(function(){ 
    
  var updated_value ='.  $id .';
  //alert(updated_value);
  
  $.ajaxSetup({
   headers : { "X-CSRF-TOKEN" :jQuery(`meta[name="csrf-token"]`). attr("content")}
  });
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url : "get_username",
    data : { id: id },
    success: function(){
   console.log(data);
    }
  });

    });';
   echo '</script>';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In all the latest **version above 5.6**, you can use like this

```
<form method="POST" action="YOUR_ACTION">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```